# Cannot import name main error

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

I want to install Pillow on Ubuntu. But I get this error:

`Import Error: cannot import name main`.

My command is:

`sudo pip install Pillow`

Thanks.

Comment: PIP issues https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240